# Defining a argument/wildcard as part of an npm's script key/name

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, npm-scripts

I have a `package.json` defined like this:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "example",

  (...)

  "scripts": {
    "something:special": "script-that-does-something.sh",
    (...)
  },

  (...)

}
```

The `script-that-does-something.sh` gets an argument to do something, meaning I'll usually do something like:

```
npm run something:special ARGUMENT
```

The above is perfectly fine and works, but I wonder if it's possible for me to define the script in the `package.json` in order to be able use any argument while still running the `npm` command like this:

```
npm run something:special:ARGUMENT
```

Comment: It's not clear what your requirement is to me, perhaps you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58092574/edit) your question to clarify. Given your current npm-script named `something:special` if you run `npm run something:special quux` (on a _*nix_ platform) then the argument (i.e. `quux`) can be accessed in the shell script (i.e. `script-that-does-something.sh`) via the `$1` positional parameter.

Comment: Is your requirement that you want to use a colon `:` as a delimiter between the npm script name and the argument - instead of a space character ?

Comment: @RobC I want to be able to have delimiters in the npm script name, where parts that are delimited are fixed, and other parts are interpreted as arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately that can't be achieved without changing the underlying functionality of the [npm cli](https://github.com/npm/cli) tool. Quite simply that feature does not exist. The only solution would be to have multiple npm scripts, i.e. one for each expected argument.

Comment: For example in the `scripts` section of _package.json_ you'd have `"something:special:foobar": "script-that-does-something.sh foobar"` , then `"something:special:quux": "script-that-does-something.sh quux",` etc etc... and you invoke them via `npm run something:special:foobar` and `npm run something:special:quux` respectively. Out of interest, why do you want the npm script key/name to include the argument and not want to pass the argument the way you usually do?

Comment: Just wanted to know if it's possible. Don't have a good reason to want it that way. I was following this last suggestion of yours up until now - setting up multiple scripts and on some of them sending arguments like one would send for any bash script once we're running  `npm run some:script:here argument`.

Answer (score -1):

I too was looking for a way to avoid having to write out every single script for my tests and commands.

At least it forces you to do some good documentation.